# Identifying two non-adjacent vertices and the effect on the Hadwiger number

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors

Suppose $G$ is a finite simple graph. Let $h(G)$ denote the *Hadwiger number*  of $G$; that is, the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

What is an example of a graph $G_0=(V_0, E_0)$ containing two non-adjacent vertices $v, w\in V_0$ such that when $v$ and $w$ are identified, the Hadwiger number of the resulting graph is smaller than $h(G_0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify two opposite vertices of the cycle graph $C_4$. This reduces the Hadwiger number from 3 to 2.